# Post method giving 200 response but in DB data is stored as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have getting 200 OK response on POST method. But data getting in DB is null. And get method working well if I manually put data in DB

my recipie model: Recipie.cs:

```
    public Guid RecipieId {get; set;}
    public string RecipieTitle{get; set;}
    public string RecipieDescription {get; set;}
    public string RecipiePhotoName{get; set;}
```

```
[HttpPost]

        public ActionResult<Recipie> AddRecipies(Recipie addnewRecipie){       
            
            recipieDbContext.Recipies.Add(addnewRecipie);
            recipieDbContext.SaveChanges();
            
            return new JsonResult(addnewRecipie);

        }
```

[image: Row 1 & 2 output when I used POSTmethod, 3&4 I manually added]

trying to pass this input in JSON format using postman

```
{       
        "RecipieTitle": "Test1",
        "RecipieDescription": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "RecipiePhotoName": "photo.png"
        
}
```

Im using Postgres. The uuid generates automatically but the data I given not getting in Db. Is there any missing details to resolve this?

Comment: what's the value of content-type header?

Comment: Could you please make me clear what is meant by content type header. How do i check that?

Comment: You should be seeing `Headers` tab in Postman in request section.

Comment: application/json

Comment: What's the response body you receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but everything worked fine. You can refer to my steps to see if some steps are missing.

Recipie.cs:

```
public class Recipie
    {
        public Guid RecipieId { get; set; }
        public string RecipieTitle { get; set; }
        public string RecipieDescription { get; set; }
        public string RecipiePhotoName { get; set; }
    }
```

DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Recipie> Recipies { get; set; }
    }
```

appsetting:

```
//Configure according to your database
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbContext": "Server=127.0.0.1; port=5432; user id = postgres; password = 12345; database=ArticleDB; pooling = true"
  }
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(P => P.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext")));
```

Migrate and update the database(If you manually create the database, you can do it without executing):

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _recipieDbContext;

        public ValuesController(MyDbContext recipieDbContext)
        { 
            _recipieDbContext = recipieDbContext;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Recipie> AddRecipies(Recipie addnewRecipie)
        {

            _recipieDbContext.Recipies.Add(addnewRecipie);
            _recipieDbContext.SaveChanges();

            return new JsonResult(addnewRecipie);

        }
    }
```

Then in Postman:
[image]

Response:
[image]

In Database:

[image]

If you compare the steps and find no problem, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't know what was the actual problem . But It worked well and updated DB also.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a request body to post data so you need to tell your controller from where it has to get data from the request so you need to put [FromBody] before your parameter type

```
public ActionResult<Recipie> AddRecipies([FromBody] Recipie addnewRecipie)
```

let me know if this will work for you or not